# Basemap: coloring shapes according to average value of points inside shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a map in matplotlib basemap, on which I draw provinces of a country using shapefiles.

I also have a list of points with a specific value. It could be a pandas dataframe, or a list of list like this:

```
[[32.1232,51.0223,80],[31.24972,51.2497,65],[32.2921,50.242,44],[32.20938,51.6069,67],[31.2480,52.2498,55]]
```

I'd like to get each province colored according to the average value of all the points within the shape.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=15,urcrnrlat=55,llcrnrlon=70,urcrnrlon=140,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')

shapefile='C:/Users/...CHN_adm_shp/CHN_adm2'
shp = m.readshapefile(shapefile, 'states', drawbounds=True)
for nshape, seg in enumerate(m.states):
poly = Polygon(seg, facecolor='0.75', edgecolor='k')
ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

The biggest hurdle I face so far is finding whether a point is inside a shape. How can this be done?